# how to change the month name column to month number column in dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, time

I have one column named Month number as Jan, Feb , Mar....
and I want to change the the whole column to number like: 01,02,03...
How to realize in python, when I use strptime, got the error like "strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series "

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following df:

```
from time import strptime
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':['Jan','Feb','Mar']})

  month  
0   Jan             
1   Feb             
2   Mar
```

You can use `strptime(x, '%b')` to convert your **abbreviated** **month** name to numbers.

```
df['month_number'] = [strptime(str(x), '%b').tm_mon for x in df['month']]
```

Result:

```
  month  month_number
0   Jan             1
1   Feb             2
2   Mar             3
```